# How do I change the contact form margin

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change my contact form margin so it starts for example 150px from the left and acts like that text in the footer "Get in touch"

Here's my website http://nothingflat.co/get-a-quote/

Comment: Can you please provide your code ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to move your form on left side remove container [screen shot](https://snag.gy/9PWLXJ.jpg)